# Backups needed?

Tags: backup

Before trusting this whole O365/sharepoint thing with the fate of our company.

Is there ANYTHING, I need to backup - or are the cloud always taking care of this for us?

Answer (score 0):

Once your content is in the cloud on SharePoint Online you can use the recycle bin(s) built into the platform and version history in your document libraries to recover documents.  Microsoft also has data protection services to prevent loss of data.  See this section on "Data backup" in the 
[SharePoint Online Service Description](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx) for the latest information.

Outside of those options there are some 3rd party solutions available to backup your content from SharePoint Online.

Comment: So, it's not like Microsoft can "malfunction" and all our documents are lost? When in the cloud, they are safe?